# Rails delayed job start after one hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I am using the delayed_job gem.

I can start a delayed job like `videofile.delay.convert_and_upload_audio_on_cdn`, 
but what is the code to start the delayed job after one hour?

Answer (score 2):

Try with something like this:

```
handle_asynchronously :in_the_future, :run_at => Proc.new { 1.hour.from_now }
```

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Answer (score 1):

From an example on another question, review the following:

```
foursquare.checkins.delay({:run_at => @time.minutes.from_now}).add(:venueId => @venue_id, :broadcast => "private")
```

In your case, it would be something like this.

```
videofile.delay({run_at: Time.now+1.hour}).convert_and_upload_audio_on_cdn
```

I haven't used that syntax myself but based on another answer, think it should work.